# Cannot find Plot Viewer in Visual Studio Python Notebook

Tags: python, visual-studio, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I saw  there is a Plot Viewer in the updated Visual Studio Python Notebook. However, it seems that I was failed to find that button within the plot. Can you lemme know how to find it ? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I don't know what `Plot Viewer` you means. Image looks like standard Notebook which normally display plot.

Comment: Ohh Thanks Furas! I just realise this is not a jupyter notebook running in VS. Would you mind letting me know how to run my ipynb file in jupyter notebook on VS? That would be appreciative  :))